# Short command to find total size of files matching a wild card

Tags: linux, bash

I could envision a simple shell script that would accomplish what I want by just iterating through a list of files in a directory and summing the individual size but was wondering if there was already a more concise way to do that.

something like

```
ls -lh *.jpg
```

that gives me the total size of just all the jpg files in the directory

Comment: `du -hsc pattern` will give you the total size of all files matching pattern.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try `du` to summarize disk usage:

```
du -csh *.jpg
```

Output (for example):

```
8.0K sane-logo.jpg
16K sane-umax-advanced.jpg
28K sane-umax-histogram.jpg
24K sane-umax.jpg
16K sane-umax-standard.jpg
4.0K sane-umax-text2.jpg
4.0K sane-umax-text4.jpg
4.0K sane-umax-text.jpg
104K total
```

`du` does not summarize the size of the files but summarizes the size of the used blocks in the file system. If a file has a size of 13K and the file system uses a block size of 4K, then 16K is shown for this file.

Answer (score 11):

For don't show files list, and just show total size, use this:

```
du -ch *.php.* | tail -1
```

Output:

```
196M    total
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this function :

```
dir () { ls -FaGl "${@}" | awk '{ last_size += $4; print }; END { print last_size }'; }
```

also you can use this command this is shorter and give you better result!

```
find YOUR_PATH -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec du -ch {} +
```

Comment: This works for directory and subdirectories.