# Output file size for all files of certain type in directory recursively?

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to get a sum of the total size of PDF files recursively within a directory. I have tried running the command below within the directory, but the recursive part does not work properly as it seems to only report on the files in the current directory and not include the directories within. I am expecting the result to be near 100 GB in size however the command is only reporting about 200 MB of files.

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | xargs du -sch
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your problem description of "does not work properly" is vague and makes it harder to answer. Can you please edit your post and include actual and expected output? For example, say "I expected it to show `16.0K ./file.pdf, 24.0K ./subdir/foo.pdf, 40.0K total` but instead it shows `16.0K ./file.pdf, 16.0K total`, which makes me think it does not recurse as it should."

Comment: Sorry! I've updated the question

Comment: So you want the sum of all files or files with sizes like iamauser posted?

Comment: The `find` command should recurse to the sub directories.  Try running it alone and see if it finds the files from subdirectories.  Note that find, by default, doesn't recurse into symbolic links, so check that the directories are not symbolic links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total size of group of files selected with 'find'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134245/608639), [Short command to find total size of files matching a wild card](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24919568/608639), [Find the total size of certain files within a directory branch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41550/56041), [Size of all files of a certain extension in a directory tree](https://askubuntu.com/q/817045), [How do I find files and total their sizes?](https://superuser.com/q/854352), etc. You have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer.

Comment: @jww Sick dude, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [total size of group of files selected with 'find'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134245/total-size-of-group-of-files-selected-with-find)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stat -c %n,%s` to get the `file name` and `size` of the individual files. Then use `awk` to sum the size and print.

```
$ find . -name '*.pdf' -exec stat -c %n,%s {} \; | awk -F, '{sum+=$2}END{print sum}'
```

In fact you don't need `%n`, since you want only the sum:

```
$ find . -name '*.pdf' -exec stat -c %s {} \; | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This seemed to list out all the files and their size but did not give the sum. How can I get the sum of the size of all the files?

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much! I've accepted your answer

Comment: In MacOS, we must use `stat -f %z` instead. Then it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of sizes of all files using:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec stat -c %s {} \; | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/'| bc
```

First `find` finds all the files as specified and for each file runs stat, which prints the file size. Then I supstitude all newline with a '+' using `tr`, then I remove the trailing '+' for the newline back and pass it to bc, which prints the sum.

Comment: Kamil, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the server did not have 'bc' installed so I was not able to see if this worked or not. iamauser's answer worked so I've accepted their answer